# Custom Dokku/Heroku buildpack can't install gems(Permission denied)

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, dokku, buildpack

When my custom buildpack runs it always fails to install gems manually(`gem install foo`) because it does not have access to the `/var/lib/gems` directory.

**Error being thrown**:

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
     Permission denied - /var/lib/gems`

---

Is there something I have to setup so my buildpack can install gems like this?

**Information**:
- Server => Ubuntu 14.04 DigitalOcean Dokku image(Latest)
- Custom Buildpack => [Noah-Huppert/buildpack-rack](https://github.com/Noah-Huppert/buildpack-rack)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`sudo chown -R $USER "/var/lib/gems"` or

`chmod -R 0777 /var/lib/gems`
if you're comfortable with giving all users on the box read/write permissions.

Comment: I can't figure out why this isn't working for me... I'm using the jekyll buildpack: https://github.com/dmathieu/heroku-buildpack-jekyll/

Comment: @SpencerAlger you should file a new question in StackOverflow as you don't quite have the same issue (it's not even the same buildpack).